# Syntax error when using Me in VB

Tags: vb6, syntax-error

Here's an interesting thing, I have used Visual Studio 2010 previously to make basic VB programs, and never had an issue with anything. Now I am just perplexed as to why this is happening.

I haven't even gotten very far into the coding phase of the first form, and already I am getting yelled at for a syntax error when I use "Me", whether it is Me.Close(), or whatever. Instead of posting the code as text here, it would be best to just show the syntax highlighting.

http://kelina-enterprises.com/img/vb-syntax-error-stackoverflow.png
::EDIT:: This image was taken down, it is not a real error.

Here's the funny thing, when I test the program, it runs just fine if I run the last successful build, which executes those "errored" lines.

Is this something I should even concern myself with, or should I just ignore these apparently false syntax errors?

Do keep in mind that if this is something simple that I have just neglected to take care of for some reason (nothing comes to mind), it has been about 3 years since I last used VB, and not even for a year at that.

Comment: That is not VB6, or even VB.  It is "VB.Net" (also known as Visual Fred, a language not even mildly related to VB even though Microsoft insists on sticking the label on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot write VB statements inside a `Class`, such as, `Me.Close()` or `MessageBox.Show("??")`. For example,

```
Class Test
    MessageBox.Show("test")
End Class
```

is obviously syntax error

Inside a `Class`, you can write only declarations or methods.

In your case, you can place the codes in the `Load` event handler like this ...

```
Private Sub LoginForm_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Fullscreen, over everything, maximized
    Me.Width = My.Computer.Screen.WorkingArea.Width
    Me.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height
    Me.CenterToScreen()
    Me.TopMost = True
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized

End Sub
```

You don't need to type-in the `Private Sub ... End Sub`. Go to form design, double click the form and the `Load` event should be appeared.

Comment: Sorry I took so long to mark this, that code has been old and dead for a while (I hate VB, and anything else exclusive to MS). I since then moved to Perl and Python. The logic and syntax is much cleaner and easier to comprehend for me, which is half the reason why I was confused about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you mean to put that code within the load event of the form, you can't have code that's not inside some sort of routine. 
If you double-click on the form in design mode, the load event should be automatically created for you and you can then move the code into it.

There are also other events of the form that you may want to use, e.g. Shown event, these can be created by clicking on the appropriate selection in the drop-down box next to the one that has LoginForm selected.